# how do i access the array in view after passing it from controller

Tags: php, laravel

```
return view($this->folder_path . 'index', compact('data' ));
```

I want to use foreach to display data.

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▶]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "test"
    "desc" => "my name"
    "age" => 12
  ]
```

This is view where i want to display data

```
@foreach($data as $item)
 <tr>
  <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
  <td>{{ ucwords($item->name) }}</td>
  <td>{{ $item->desc }}</td>
  <td>{{ $item->age }}</td>
 <tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, hard to read. [Edit] your question and paste the code there. Thanks

Comment: What does "_not working_" mean? Blank page? No data shown? Wrong data shown? Any error?

Comment: Shot in the dark: iirc `data`/`$data` has a "special meaning" in Laravel when passing data to views. Try using a different name for `data`. Also maybe `{{ dd($data) }}` in your view to see what it contains

Comment: It has the array of data

Answer (score 1):

Your `$data` and each `$item` appear to be [`arrays`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and not [`objects`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php), therefore using the `object` accessor (`->`) on `$item` will not work. Instead you should be accessing the elements of your `$item` array using their key names:

```
@foreach($data as $item)
 <tr>
  <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
  <td>{{ ucwords($item['name']) }}</td>
  <td>{{ $item['desc'] }}</td>
  <td>{{ $item['age'] }}</td>
 <tr>
@endforeach
```

Probably worthwhile doing some reading on [associative arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_associative.asp).